# SQL sum group by column including rows of same table as dependents

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, inner-join

I want to see how many messages are sent by users, so I have tables where I store the channel and another table where I store the authors and the actual data. An important part of this is that channels can be subchannels, meaning that they are children of another channel, but also have their own ID.

## Table 1

| Row ID | Guild ID | Channel ID | Parent Channel ID (foreign key on Table 1 Channel ID) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | null |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | null |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 3 |

## Table 2

| Row ID | Parent Channel ID (foreign key on Table 1 Channel ID) | Author ID | Messages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 54 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | 3 |

I have a query that gets the sum of messages from Channel IDs that are not a child of any other channel ID:

```sql
SELECT sc."guild_id" guild, sc."channel_id" channel, sum(s."NUM") num
FROM statistic s
         INNER JOIN statschannel sc on s.parent_channel_id = sc.channel_id
GROUP BY sc."guild_id", sc."channel_id";
```

I would like to change the query so that the `SUM()` of `(GUILD ID 1, CHANNEL ID 3)` includes the sum of `(GUILD ID 1, CHANNEL ID 4)`, as channel with ID 4 is a child channel. I tried doing an inner join, show below, but it only returns the results for the channels *with* a parent ID.

```sql
SELECT sc."guild_id" guild, sc."channel_id" channel, sum(s."NUM") num
FROM statistic s
         INNER JOIN statschannel sc on s.parent_channel_id = sc.channel_id
         INNER JOIN statschannel sc2 on sc.parent_channel_id = sc2.channel_id
GROUP BY sc."guild_id", sc."channel_id";
```

I don't know what to do here. The data that I want returned should look like this:

| Guild ID | Channel ID | Messages |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 6 |
| 1 | 3 | 57 ( 54 + 3) |
| 1 | 4 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make a solution that provided the results I wanted.

```sql
SELECT "statschannel"."guild_id"          "guild_id",
       "statschannel"."channel_id"        "channel_id",
       SUM("statistic2"."NUM") + COALESCE(SUM("statistic"."NUM"), 0)            "num"
FROM "statschannel"
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "statschannel" "statschannel__parent_channel"
                         ON "statschannel__parent_channel"."channel_id" =
                            "statschannel"."parent_channel_id"
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "statistic" ON "statschannel__parent_channel"."channel_id" =
                                        "statistic"."parent_channel_id"
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "statistic" "statistic2" ON "statschannel".channel_id =
                                                    "statistic2".parent_channel_id
GROUP BY statschannel."guild_id", "statschannel"."channel_id"
```

This will provide the following results:

| guild_id | channel_id | messages |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 6 |
| 1 | 3 | 57 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 |